# How many zeros within a number

Tags: number-theory

Let noughts(n) be the number of noughts needed to write n in base 10.If n is given how can I find out the value of noughts(n) .

I myself have tried to compute noughts(n) by examining all the digits of n.But the method appears to me as an inefficient and slower one.
Is there any recursive formula to compute noughts(n).

Comment: Perhaps it's mildly related to the problem of [counting ones in a binary number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)?

Comment: Examining digits isn’t all that inefficient, since it’s $\log n$: $(1)$ Set $k=0$. $(2)$ If $\frac{n}{10}=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor$, set $k$ to $k+1$. $(3)$ Set $n$ to $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor$. $(4)$ If $n>0$, go to $(2)$, else return $k$. I don’t know of a nice recursive description, and I’d be a little surprised if you could do much better unless you could take advantage of some specific machine architecture.